# Using EntityManager already created with @Transactional DeltaSpike

Tags: jpa, cdi, deltaspike

I'm trying to use @Transactional by DeltaSpike library, but i have some problems with it. Let's see:

1) I have a DAO producer that creates a EntityManager using a custom qualifier.

```
@Produces
    @PersistenceUnitName(value="")
    public DAO criar(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String persistenceUnit = "";
        EntityManager em = null;

        for (Annotation annotation : ip.getQualifiers()) {
            if (annotation instanceof PersistenceUnitName) {

                persistenceUnit = ((PersistenceUnitName) annotation).value();
            }
        }
        em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit).createEntityManager();

        return new DAO(em);
    }
```

Now imagine that i'm inject DAO in other class:

```
@Inject @PersistenceUnit(value="myPU01")
    private DAO dao;
```

The producer is called and EntityManager is created using myPU01. But inside DAO class i have a method save and i would like to use @Transactional from DeltaSpike lib:

```
@Transactional
    public void save(AbstractEntity entidade) {
        em.persist(entidade);
        em.flush();
    }
```

The problem lives here. The @Transactional will try to create another EntityManager but i already have a EntityManager created with myPU01. I can't put the persistenceUnitName beside "save".

Comment: Calling `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit)` for every created object seems to be an extremely bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need an own producer for the Entity-Manager (with a useful scope e.g. @TransactionScoped). Inject this Entity-Manager in your beans as well as in the Producer-Method for your DAO (as a parameter).
That are the rules for CDI and *no* issue/limitation/... of DeltaSpike.

Comment: FYI: If you would have asked the community directly, you would have received an answer within few hours.

Comment: Can you give me some example ?